# Formulario en Angular POST

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Estoy utilizando una api rest y necesito un formulario que agregue ciudades ya tengo : Ciudad.module.ts, ciudad.service.ts el cual necesito utilizar el metodo POST obteniendo el usuario y el token

Ciudad.module.ts :

```
export class Ciudad {
id: number;
nombre: string;
poblacion: string;

}
```

Ciudad.service.ts

```
readonly ciurl = "https://localhost:44359/api/ciudad";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private   authSession: UserService) 
{ }


 setUserLoggedIn(){
  localStorage.getItem('Token');
  alert("token");
  }
}
```

Este es el home.ts
       constructor(private service : CiudadService) { }

```
  ngOnInit() {

    var  token = localStorage.getItem('Token');
    var user = localStorage.getItem('Username');
```

}

```
resetForm(form?: NgForm){
  if(form!= null)
  form.resetForm();
  this.service.formData = {
    id : null,
    nombre : '',
    poblacion : ''
  }
}
onSubmit(form : NgForm){
  const newcuidad : CiudadService = Object.assign({}, this.service);
}
```

}

Y este es el formulario

```
   <form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" (submit)="onSubmit(form)" 
 style="width: 80%; margin-left: 30px">
            <div class="form-group" >
              <label for="id">id</label>
              <input type="number" name="id" #id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.id" class="form-control validate" required>
              <div class="validation-error" >This Field is required.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Ciudad">Ciudad</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control validate"  name="ciudad" #ciudad="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.ciudad" required>
              <div class="validation-error" >This Field is required.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Ciudad">Población</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control validate" name="poblacion" #poblacion="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.poblacion" required>
                <div class="validation-error" >This Field is required.</div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save changes</button>
                </div>
          </form>
```

Quiero saber como puedo hacer que me funcione el POST con este formulario

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de enviar la información.
Una como estas haciendo con [(ngModel)]="valor"

```
onSubmit(form : NgForm){
  const newcuidad ={
id: this.id,
ciudad: this.ciudad,
poblacion: this.poblacion
};
this.servicio.createCiudad(newcuidad).toPromise().then(resp =>{
   console.log("resp", resp);
}).catch(error =>{
   console.log("error ", error );
});

}
// en el servicio
createCiudad(ciudad){
   let body = ciudad;
   // hay que declarar los headers en el servico con el backend
   return this.http.post(url+"createCiudad",body,{headers:headers} ).pipe(map(resp => resp))
}
// or
createCiudad(ciudad){
   let body = ciudad;
   // hay que declarar los headers en el servico con el backend y el cors
   return this.http.post(url+"createCiudad",body,{headers:headers} ).pipe(map(resp => {
reuturn resp; // por si quieres hacer alguna consulta.
}));
}
```

// Aunque no me queda claro service.formdata ?
También te aconsejo que mires los reactive forms. Te dejo unos links para que los veas.
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms 
y algunos videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmQfhWJGCoY&list=PLcLoUdtOOXL34dK3xIZaAsc-EEo1O0CGP&index=8
Desde el vídeo el video 10 explican los rective forms
Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo.